# Element jr:Code128 is not allowed here

Tags: java, jasper-reports, barcode4j

I am creating a report using iReport's component Code128 from package barcode4j, however in the xml, jr:Code128 can't be recognized, codes are as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.18.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.18.1-9d75d1969e774d4f179fb3be8401e98a0e6d1611  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="2011.2" pageWidth="283" pageHeight="85" columnWidth="199" leftMargin="42" rightMargin="42" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <field name="barcode1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="85">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="4" y="7" width="66" height="41" uuid="4155ca0c-0f85-4c16-8b19-87c74019e928"/>
                <jr:Code128 xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" textPosition="bottom">
                    <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$F{barcode1}]]></jr:codeExpression>
                </jr:Code128>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Here is how I tried to solve:
Adding dependency as

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.18.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Including jar files into intellij modules:

[image]

Couldn't solve the issue, could anyone help please?

Comment: Did you check same report from Jaspersoft Studio? Does it work?

Comment: I did but it's the same, btw the solution seems to be that you have to combine and run the code even with the "jr:Code128 not allowed here" warning anyway, it just works!!!!